# How to use Active Report with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, wcf, activereports

How to use Active Report with AngularJs

I'm newbie and i can't find tutorial of ActiveReport with AngularJS

how to create active report service and generate report from AngularJS

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the following blog post which explains how to use ActiveReports with AngularJS - http://arhelp.grapecity.com/2014/05/28/activereports-8-html5-viewer-and-angularjs/

Comment: Thank, can i export pdf directly not by viewer.

Comment: You can export through javascript. Check the 'export' method at the following documentation link: http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR11/index.html#HTML5WorkingwithViewerUsingJavascript.html